# Receiving RTSP video streams to multiple canvas using vlcj

Tags: java, video-streaming, vlcj

I'm trying to receive multiple rtsp video streams from phones to my PC application using Canvas,

but I'm testing with just 2 videos first.
Here is the code I'm using for now.

```
final String url = "rtsp://192.168.173.217:8085";
final String url2 = "rtsp://192.168.173.104:8086";

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //new MediaPlayer(filePath);
            MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();

            CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas1);
            EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(videoSurface);

            CanvasVideoSurface videoSurface2 = mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvas2);
            EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer2 = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer2.setVideoSurface(videoSurface2);

            mediaPlayer2.playMedia(url2);
            mediaPlayer.playMedia(url);

        }
    });
```

The thing is that this works well with video files or single rtsp stream but doesn't work on multiple streams.

It acts like all streams are contained in the same canvas following with these errors (Well, only some of them).

```
[h264 @ 1774e6e0] decode_slice_header error
[H264 Decoder @ 17df9720] invalid mixed IDR / non IDR frames cannot be decoded in slice multithreading mode
[h264 @ 1774e6e0] illegal memory management control operation 32
```

Comment: You should post a full code sample really, not a fragment. You don't show how you create canvas1 and canvas2 for example. Anyway, those objects you create in the run() method become eligible for garbage collection when the run method exits, so that will likely cause you some problems - even if not specifically the problem you're asking about.  You need to keep a hard reference to all of the vlcj objects.

Comment: I just found that the problem might didn't come from the code but the VLC itself. I tried to open 2 streams in separate VLC windows, but 2 streams are contained in only one windows and the other shows blank. So maybe the problem is from my server code now. I'll look more about this, thanks